# not visible posts on facebook pages wall posted in php, no error in result

Tags: php, facebook

I did automatic posting products from online shop to facebook page.

My client is owner/manager of the page. I was granted administrator rights to this page.

I have own one personal/developer fb account at the same time.

My own page is successfully updated by second fb application by the same script (config is different). The results are similar(running script targeted my page and my client's page) - no errors.
But my client's page is not showing those posts.

Both apps are live(not in sandbox mode).

(I can't login with client's credentials.) - but could it be the problem? do I have to be the creator of the page?

Comment: Is the app out of developer mode …?

Comment: the apps are out of developer mode

Comment: So are you using a page access token then to make the posts?

Comment: very very long access tokens - (different for each app)

Comment: If you want help, then please actually answer my question.

Comment: And if you don’t know what’s what, then first of all go read up on access tokens in the docs, and second of all check your access token using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Both apps are live(not in sandbox mode). - updated the description just after your question

Comment: Resolved: I was using 'user access token' instead of page access token. Now even when my client didnt give me his credentials and after obtaining a page access token posting works.